# Checking the specific type of object of an argument with type "Object"

Tags: java, oop, object

```
public class Tuple {
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    // Compare if Tuple is equal to specified object o
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // code goes here
    }

    // ...
}
```

I have a Tuple class for Tuple objects and one of the methods is to check if an object is equal to a Tuple object. I won't specify what determines equality between two Tuples, but what I'm confused about is how to deal with the fact that the parameter argument for the equals() method is an 'Object'. Obviously, if the object is not even a Tuple, I return false--what is the best way to do this?

I know there are methods such as instanceof and getClass, but is the correct/recommended way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!(o instanceof Tuple))
    return false;
Tuple other = (Tuple) o;
...
```

Comment: You don't need to check for null, `instanceof` does that for you. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the object `o` to `Tuple` to compare the attributes of `Tuple`. You should compare whether the input object is of type `Tuple` using `instanceOf` operator before casting.

Comment: This, but you need to make sure it is a Tuple before casting or you will get a ClassCastException

Comment: @Jems agreed there should be multiple checks such as whether the input is not null, whether it is an instanceOf tuple. But i answered directly to what the question is. I will be adding more details .

Answer (score 0):

You have to review your business requirement, but in most cases if the type is different then it will be deemed inequal -- you can't even compare other object unless it's the same type / subtype. Hence:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if(! (o instanceof Tuple)) return false;
  Tuple other = (Tuple) o;
  // do your comparison logic here
}
```